# Combining multiple left join for one single line

Tags: mysql, innodb, index, join

We have a query as below.

```
SELECT tblSData.header,
tblEAlert.eMessage
FROM tblSData
LEFT JOIN tblEAlert ON tblSData.sDataID=tblEAlert.sDataID 
Where tblSData.aID=".$aID." Order By tblSData.dateTimer  Asc
```

Structure for the tables are as below:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tblSData` (
  `sDataID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
  `header` varchar(255) NOT NULL,   
  `aID` int(5) NOT NULL,
  `gFInID` int(5) NOT NULL,
  `gFOutID` int(5) NOT NULL,
  `gFAInID` int(5) NOT NULL,
  `gFAOutID` int(5) NOT NULL,
  `eAlertID` int(5) NOT NULL,
  `dateTimer` datetime NOT NULL
   PRIMARY KEY (`sDataID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tblEAlert` (
  `eAlertID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `sDataID` int(5) NOT NULL,
  `eID` int(5) NOT NULL,
  `aID` int(5) NOT NULL,
  `eDateTime` datetime NOT NULL,
  `eInsertDateTime` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `eMessage` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`eAlertID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;


Sample data for tblSData

1,"A1",1122,100,102,1,2,1,2013-07-13 15:30:19
2,"A3",1122,104,103,3,4,3,2013-07-13 15:45:19
3,"A4",1122,105,108,5,6,7,2013-07-13 15:55:19


Sample data for tblEAlert

1,1,1,1122,2013-07-13 15:30:19,2013-07-13 15:30:19,"Alert 1"
2,1,2,1122,2013-07-13 15:30:19,2013-07-13 15:30:19,"Alert 2"
3,2,2,1122,2013-07-13 15:45:19,2013-07-13 15:45:19,"Alert 3"
4,2,3,1122,2013-07-13 15:45:19,2013-07-13 15:45:19,"Alert 4"
5,2,4,1122,2013-07-13 15:45:19,2013-07-13 15:45:19,"Alert 5"
6,2,5,1122,2013-07-13 15:45:19,2013-07-13 15:45:19,"Alert 6"
```

Sample output is.

```
"A1","Alert 1"
"A1","Alert 2"
"A2","Alert 3"
"A2","Alert 4"
"A2","Alert 5"
"A2","Alert 6"
```

The problem now is how to show say for e.g. A1 all the Alert Message in one line and same goes for A2 etc. Now each alert message is on a different line.

Answer (score 2):

Use the [**GROUP_CONCAT**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) function

```
SELECT header,GROUP_CONCAT(eMessage) ErrorMessages FROM
(
    SELECT tblSData.header,IFNULL(tblEAlert.eMessage,'') eMessage
    FROM tblSData
    LEFT JOIN tblEAlert ON tblSData.sDataID=tblEAlert.sDataID 
    Where tblSData.aID=".$aID." Order By tblSData.dateTimer  Asc
) A
GROUP BY header;
```

or

```
SELECT tblSData.header,GROUP_CONCAT(IFNULL(tblEAlert.eMessage,'')) ErrorMessages 
FROM tblSData
LEFT JOIN tblEAlert ON tblSData.sDataID=tblEAlert.sDataID 
Where tblSData.aID=".$aID." Order By tblSData.dateTimer  Asc
GROUP BY header;
```

A good index to create for this would be

```
ALTER TABLE tblSData ADD INDEX (aID,dateTimer);
```

What good will this index do ?

- This will get everything for a specific `aID`
- All `aID` rows are  ordered by `dateTimer`
- The `sDataID` column will be available for use from the index rather than the table because the Clustered Index will include the PRIMARY KEY anyway.

You should also create this one

```
ALTER TABLE tblEAlert ADD INDEX (sDataID);
```

Give it a Try !!!

Comment: What are the indexes should I use in this case? Which one will be more efficient the first or second ?

Comment: Updated my answer with the needed indexes. As for which query to pick, the second one will have a simpler explain plan in the Query Optimizer. Yet, you should create the index, try both queries, run `EXPLAIN` on both queries. Then, judge performance from there...

Comment: I am kind of new to indexing and finding a bit difficult to decide at time what combination index to pick. I know most of the time you look for the where statement. The problem is that at times we have more then 1 where based on a particular field and another where statement picking another field? So in that case we need two separate indexing right? I am not clear here The sDataID column will be available for use from the index rather than the table because the Clustered Index will include the PRIMARY KEY anyway.?

Comment: I tried both is taking too long and it only give result with those having the message in tblEAlert which is not suppose to be the case right?

Comment: Oh that's right you did a LEFT JOIN. Let me adjust my answer...

Comment: by right those without the message also should be shown up right? I have added the index not much of help either?

Comment: Perhaps the index is only good for an INNER JOIN. A full index scan would probably occur on the LEFT JOIN.

Comment: @Another thing I was thinking is that two keep a bool value in tblSData if it true then run another inner query for tblEAlert. So in my php this will be 2 separate queries what you say ?

Comment: any idea please?